# Unity Moving and rotating part of a model

Tags: unity

I have downloaded a high quality head model which includes the shoulder, and I have want to move and rotate the head model, but its shoulder fixed, as if it is looking at the certain points that I have as list. I am not sure what is the best way to implement this -- should I split the model into two parts with blender, and just move the head model? Or should write a script that only moves the part of the model. If I write a script, how do I locate specific vertices in the model(in my case, the tip of the nose would be best) to follow the coordinates in the list, and how do I specify other vertices in meshes that needs to be follow the change so that the movement would look natural?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to do this is through the [Unity animation system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationOverview.html). When a 3d artist creates a model of a character in a 3d modeling program, they usually also add a "rig" to it (a collection of bones connected to vertices which can be moved in order to move parts of the whole 3d model) and also define a couple animations.

Another important component of a good character rig are [Inverse Kinematic](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InverseKinematics.html) ("IK") Targets. They allow to animate parts of a model in a way which takes an arbitrary point in 3d space as input. This is often used to implement abilities like grabbing things or (relevant in your use-case) looking at things.

A 3d engine like Unity can then use that rig to modify the 3d model in real-time by playing animations, moving bones or moving IK target points.

If the 3d model you got doesn't have a rig which allows to move the head separately from the shoulders, then you might have to build your own rig. Consult the documentation of your preferred 3d modeling program for details. If you want to use Blender and have any Blender-specific questions about character rigging and animation, then you might want to check out our sister site [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks! I think my model doesn't have a rig, does unity support rigging or is blender better way to do this? I am more used to unity, never actually used blender before.

Comment: @YongHyunKwon Rigging is something you should do in a 3d modeling program.